# modification time rsync option?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, rsync

i use `rsync` tools between two server but it seem rsync make synchronous between servers according to file size and i need to make synchronous according modification time please how i can do it

for example 
 file in date 2-3-2011
then updated on  5-3-2011

i want rsync to take the latest one 5-3-2011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync` doesn't just work based on filesize; modification time is taken into account. You can also do it with checksums by using the `--checksum` option.

Take a look at this site for a detailed explanation of the `rsync` process: http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/how-rsync-works.html

Answer (score 0):

rsync by default will use mod-time and size. Not sure why you would want to use it based on mod-time alone when size is a really effective quick check.

Comment: i need mod-time because some in some files i change data like "date" so that size didn't change

Comment: Okay, well that's done by default automatically.